# Peg Solitaire - Stuck on creating a state array

Tags: c++

I need to modify a state array to use only four bits per state. As there is no native 4-bit type, you will need to use a larger type and bit manipulations to get and set the bits for each state. These four bits will be used for two purposes.

a. Two of the four bits will represent 4 values: Already seen, current depth, next depth, and
unseen. This will efficiently mark what states should be expanded in the current iteration
and future iterations.

b. The other bits will store the depth of each state modulo 4. This is sufficient information to extract the path from the board.

Yes, this is a HW question so I don't expect an answer, just guidance. I'm am unsure how to proceed with my determineStateInfo function. Here is my current code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
enum state {NEXT_DEPTH = 2, UNSEEN = 3, CURRENT_DEPTH = 1, ALREADY_SEEN = 0};

bool valid[56] =
{
    false, false, false,  false, false, false, false,
    false,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false,
    false,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false,
    false,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false,
    false,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false,
    false,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false,
    false,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false,
    false, false, false,  false, false, false, false
};

struct PegState {
    bool board[56];
};

struct PegAction {
    int from, to, middle;
};

PegState GetStartState()
{
    PegState s;
    for (int x = 0; x < 56; x++)
    {
        s.board[x] = true;
    }
    s.board[24] = 0;
    return s;
}

uint32_t GetHashFromState(PegState s)
{
    uint32_t hash = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 56; x++)
    {
        if (valid[x])
            hash = (hash<<1)|(s.board[x]?1:0);
    }
    return hash;
}

PegState GetStateFromHash(uint32_t hash)
{
    PegState s;
    for (int x = 55; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        if (valid[x])
        {
            s.board[x] = hash&0x1;
            hash = hash>>1;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

uint32_t GetMaxHashValue()
{
    uint32_t vals = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 55; x++)
    {
        if (valid[x])
            vals = (vals<<1)|1;
    }
    return vals;
//  return 0xFFFFFFFFul;
}

void Print(PegState s)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
            if (valid[x+y*7])
            {
                printf("%c", s.board[x+y*7]?'o':'.');
            }
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
}

std::vector<PegAction> GetLegalActions(PegState s)
{
    std::vector<PegAction> moves;
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < 7; y++)
        {
            if (valid[x+0+y*7] && valid[x+1+y*7] && valid[x+2+y*7])
            {
                // right
                if ((s.board[x+0+y*7] == true) &&
                    (s.board[x+1+y*7] == true) &&
                    (s.board[x+2+y*7] == false))
                {
                    PegAction a;
                    a.from = x+0+y*7;
                    a.middle = x+1+y*7;
                    a.to = x+2+y*7;
                    moves.push_back(a);
                }
                // left
                if ((s.board[x+0+y*7] == false) &&
                    (s.board[x+1+y*7] == true) &&
                    (s.board[x+2+y*7] == true))
                {
                    PegAction a;
                    a.from = x+2+y*7;
                    a.middle = x+1+y*7;
                    a.to = x+0+y*7;
                    moves.push_back(a);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x = 1; x < 6; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
        {
            if (valid[x+(y+0)*7] && valid[x+(y+1)*7] && valid[x+(y+2)*7])
            {
                // down
                if ((s.board[x+(y+0)*7] == true) &&
                    (s.board[x+(y+1)*7] == true) &&
                    (s.board[x+(y+2)*7] == false))
                {
                    PegAction a;
                    a.from = x+(y+0)*7;
                    a.middle = x+(y+1)*7;
                    a.to = x+(y+2)*7;
                    moves.push_back(a);
                }
                // up
                if ((s.board[x+(y+0)*7] == false) &&
                    (s.board[x+(y+1)*7] == true) &&
                    (s.board[x+(y+2)*7] == true))
                {
                    PegAction a;
                    a.from = x+(y+2)*7;
                    a.middle = x+(y+1)*7;
                    a.to = x+(y+0)*7;
                    moves.push_back(a);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return moves;
}

PegState ApplyAction(PegState s, PegAction a)
{
    assert(s.board[a.from] == true);
    s.board[a.from] = false;
    assert(s.board[a.middle] == true);
    s.board[a.middle] = false;
    assert(s.board[a.to] == false);
    s.board[a.to] = true;

    return s;
}

void undo()
{

}

void reverse()
{

}

void setBit(uint8_t *array, const uint32_t hash, const uint8_t new_info)
{
    assert(new_info == (new_info&0xF));
    const uint8_t index ( hash/2 );
    if(hash%2 == 0) //even
    {
        array[index] &= 0xF;  //00001111
        array[index] |= new_info << 4;
    }
    else
    {
        array[index] &= 0xF0;   //11110000
        array[index] |= new_info;
    }
}

uint8_t getStateInformation(const uint8_t *array, const uint32_t hash)
{
    const uint8_t index ( hash/2 );
    if(hash%2 == 0) //even
        return array[index] & 0xF;
    else
        return array[index] & 0xF0;
}

void savestate(PegState *temp)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("state.txt", "w+");

    for (int x = 0; x < 55; x++) {}
        //fwrite(&temp.board[x], sizeof(PegState), 1, f);
}

uint8_t determineStateInfo(uint8_t status, uint32_t depth)
{
    if(status == CURRENT_DEPTH)
    {

    }
    else if(status == ALREADY_SEEN)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}

bool compare(uint8_t stateInfo)
{
    if(stateInfo == 0xF)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void BFS()
{
    // initialize memory, 1 byte per state, to store the depth of the state
    uint32_t maxVal = GetMaxHashValue();
    int8_t *dist = new int8_t[maxVal];

    // reset all memory to -1 (unseen)
    for (uint32_t x = 0; x < maxVal; x++)
        dist[x] = -1;

    // Set the start state to depth 0
    PegState s = GetStartState();
    dist[GetHashFromState(s)] = 0;
    Print(s);

    printf("Ready to begin search\n");

    // Loop through all states; any at the current depth should:
    //   * Have their legal actions generated
    //   * Find all possible successor states
    //   * Write the depth of the successors
    // Repeat the loop until no states are updated in the loop
    int update = 0;
    int expand = 0;
    int currDepth = 0;
    do {
        expand = 0;
        update = 0;
        for (uint32_t x = 0; x < maxVal; x++)
        {
            uint8_t i = getStateInformation(dist[x], maxVal);
//          if (0 == x%100000000)
//              printf("%ul\n", x);
            if (dist[x] == currDepth)
            {
                expand++;
                s = GetStateFromHash(x);
                std::vector<PegAction> m = GetLegalActions(s);
                for (unsigned int t = 0; t < m.size(); t++)
                {
                    PegState res = ApplyAction(s, m[t]);
                    uint32_t rank = GetHashFromState(res);
                    if (dist[rank] == -1)
                    {
                        dist[rank] = currDepth+1;
                        update++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Depth %d; %d expanded; %d unique generated\n",currDepth, expand, update);
        currDepth++;
    } while (update > 0);

    for (uint32_t x = 0; x < maxVal; x++)
    {
        if (dist[x] == (currDepth-1) || dist[x] == 0)
        {
            s = GetStateFromHash(x);
            Print(s);
        }
    }
    // Print statistics about the search
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    BFS();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the olden days of C, you can create a 4-bit variable by placing it into a structure:

```
struct PegState
{
    unsigned int view:2;
    unsigned int depth:2;
};
```

For a more compact representation, the requirements says it all:  use bit manipulation operations.
To set a bit, use the 'OR' operator, '|':

```
unsigned int value = value | 16;
value |= (1 << 8);
```

To erase a bit, use the 1's compliment and the 'AND' operator, '&':

```
unsigned int value = 0xFF;
value = value & (~(1 << 5));
```

To test the bit you can use the AND operator:

```
unsigned int value = 0x55;
if (value & (1 << 2))
{
}
```

Search SO and the web for "bit manipulation".

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand the bit manipulation, but how would I go from the Breadth first search to marking the states?

Comment: Calculating bit positions is a little bit more work than indexing a matrix (board).  Use the `sizeof` operator to determine the capacity of your bit container (int, short int, byte, long, etc) in `char`s.  Next, use `CHAR_BIT` (from <climits>), to determine the number of bits per `char`.  For example, if `sizeof(unsigned int)` is 4 and CHAR_BIT is 8, your `unsigned int` will hold 4 * 8 or 32 bits.  Divide the ordinate by `sizeof` to get the byte container, then use shifting to get the appropriate bit.